# JAVA How to call a void method from another class and read public String method?

Tags: java

I have a big problem, my project has three classes. (Strings, GetStrings, Main).

My First Class File,

```
public class ProgramConfig {    

 public String strVersionNumber = "1.0.0";
 public String strProgramName = "TestProgramName";
```

}

My Second Class File(GetConfig),

```
public class GetProgramConfig {

ProgramConfig ProgramConfig;

public String GetLocalVersionNumber(){
    return ProgramConfig.strVersionNumber;
}

public String GetProgramName(){
    return ProgramConfig.strProgramName;
}
```

And my problem was here. I can't call anything from class file. Here a sample,

GetProgramConfig cfg;
String testStr = cfg.GetProgramName();

Problem

i.hizliresim.com/e7JVdm.png

And void call,

i.hizliresim.com/e7JVdm.png

delete {}

Comment: 1. Post the error which you're getting (in the question itself, not to an external links) 2. `ProgramConfig ProgramConfig` is not a valid declaration, since you're not even creating a variable here, note Java is a case sensitive 3. Clearly explain the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the class properly.You have keep the Object name same as Class name,its totally wrong habit.Change the object name as below :

Updated code as below :

```
public class GetProgramConfig {

    ProgramConfig programConfig = new ProgramConfig(); // Initial it properly

    public String GetLocalVersionNumber(){
        return programConfig.strVersionNumber;
    }

    public String GetProgramName(){
        return programConfig.strProgramName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetProgramConfig cfg = new GetProgramConfig(); // Initialize it properly
        String testStr = cfg.GetProgramName();

        System.out.println(testStr); //Ouput:TestProgramName
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't work because of `ProgramConfig ProgramConfig... `.

Comment: what do you mean @PradeepSimha ??

Comment: Because it's not a valid variable declaration :)

Comment: `ProgramConfig ProgramConfig` wont work, because its invalide declaration of variables.

Comment: @PradeepSimha we can keep the object name same as Class name.I accept that its bad habbit

Comment: @Salah Its valid declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declaare a valid veriable and initialze it:

```
ProgramConfig programConfig = new ProgramConfig();
```

instead of

```
ProgramConfig ProgramConfig;
```

also create getters to your instance veriables like:

```
public String getStrVersionNumber() {
    return strVersionNumber;
}
```

and `GetProgramConfig` class do like this:

```
public String GetProgramName(){
    return programConfig.getStrVersionNumber();
}
```